# SQL Server Compact edition 3.5 database acess is denied

Tags: c#, error-handling, sql-server-ce

I have developed a desktop application in C# with Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5.

It works fine when I run `.exe` file from solution folder (`bin\release` or `debug`) but when I tried to deploy it by creating its setup it shows unhandled exception:

> You don't have permission to access CustomersDB.sdf file.

Note there is no path error it is correct.

```
string lokasifile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\CustomersDB.sdf";
string stringkoneksi = "Data Source = \"" + lokasifile + "\"";
SqlCeConnection koneksi = new SqlCeConnection(stringkoneksi);
koneksi.Open();
```

Comment: As I see permission error, I immediately think of running it as an administrator or moving your file to some other place. Quite not sure if it'd work, but there's nothing bad in trying after all... :D

Comment: The account running the website in the app pool does not have rights to the sdf file.  Give it rights to that file.  Alternatively, that file doesn't exist where you think it is.  You should be using App_Data and |DataDirectory|, anyhow.  If you did that, it would work as expected all the time, no worries.

Comment: SQL CE doesn't allow multiple concurrent connection at once btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecurityException
```

This is nothing but caller does not have the appropriate permission.
[Environment.CurrentDirectory Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
try
{
     //Call Path here you will get to what the exactly error is
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     if (ex is DirectoryNotFoundException|| ex is IOException|| ex is SecurityException)
     {
          //Your handling here
     }
     else
     {
          throw;
     }
}
```

Comment: directory exists ,file exists and, path is correct the problem is only access is denied.

Comment: Give required permission to that file in properties

Comment: that is the problem "how to set permission"

Comment: Right-click the file or folder for which you want to set permissions, click Properties, and then click the Security tab.
Click Edit to open the Permissions for <Object> dialog box.